# Make Div 100% of grandparent container?

Tags: css

Here's the problem I have:-

I have one div that is set to a max width of 960px.

The width of the div inside the div is set to 100%, but 100% means a max of 960px

How can I make the div inside the 960px div become 100% of the user's screen, without moving the child div(100%) out of the parent div(960px)?

**EDIT FOR FURTHER CLARIFICATION. 
Here's the structure:-**

```
 gParentDiv
    parentDiv
       myDiv
```

I want myDiv to be the same width as gParentDiv, but keep it within parentDiv

I hope you can help

Comment: Do you just want to stretch some div on the entire screen. or there's a special need to make it 100% percent wide inside its own container?

Comment: Italy, yes, I want to stretch the child div, so that it is the full width of the gradparent div

Comment: What do you want? Quote: "become 100% of the user's screen" OR "same width as gParentDiv".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Break element out of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723417/break-element-out-of-container)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the viewport's height and width.

For example, the following class will make the element the size of the viewport.

```
.fullscreen {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/52jXj/1/)

This is a **pure CSS3** solution, but it has some [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) issues.

---

If you just want to strech an element on the entire screen you can use a different approach.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/52jXj/2/)

```
.fullscreen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Any way to do it without Javascript?

Comment: There's no JS in my answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you want the div to become '100% of the user's screen' (viewport), then the answers of @Itay and @Fujy are both correct.

If you want the same position as the grandparent (960px), then first define a reset to the dimensions of the grandgrandparent (body). Then position the child the same way as the grandparent. Consider this code:

```
<body>
    <div id="grandparent">
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="reset">
                <div id="child">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice the `<body>` is the same width as the viewport and the grandparent will be positioned relative to this body/viewport. The child needs to be positioned in the same way as the grandparent. So first reset to the viewport: `#reset ( position:absolute; left:0; right:0; }`. Now it's easy to give the child the same declarations as the grandparent.

The body/viewport/grandgrandparent is white, grandparent gray, parent blue, reset red and child green:

[image: Screenshot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        #grandparent {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: lightgray;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #parent {
            width: 320px;
            margin-left: 480px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.30);
            padding: 12px;
        }

        #reset {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.30);
            padding: 12px;
        }

        #child { 
            width: 960px; /* same as grandparent */ 
            margin: 0 auto; /* same as grandparent */ 
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: rgba(0,255,0,.30);
            padding: 12px 0;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grandparent">
        <h1>Grandparent</h1>
        <div id="parent">
            <p>The parent can be anywhere.</p>
            <div id="reset">
                <div id="child">
                    <p>Child has same position as grandparent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note 1: `#parent { ... }` and all `border`, `background` and `padding` are only to make the div's visible.

Note 2: The y-position is still relative to the parent. For y-axis reset use `top:0; bottom:0;`.

Comment: One drawback with this is that the absolute positioning on the reset causes the child content to flow over top of whatever stuff comes after it. So I guess it doesn't work when you have varying content in and after the child element.

Comment: @allcaps What if you're working with percentages, not pixles?

Comment: Can this be done without `position: absolute`? Like having 4 elements with `25%` width that are positioned one next to another?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about setting to 100% width of grandparent. This just hardcodes the width to 960px.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `absolute` position

```
 .child-div {
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     right:0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, so regardless of screensize, my child div will appear at the top-left of the screen with this code?

Comment: @user2692219 this will work. Play around with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_absolute

Comment: Absolute position works, but it is by no means the best way of accomplishing things. It can cause problems for smaller screens and resizing. Use it only when absolutely necessary (pun intended)