# Converting a static slider to responsive one

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, slider

I created my own slider using jQuery, but it is of fixed length. I want to make this responsive using a pure CSS approach, as I don't want to use JavaScript / jQuery for all the elements to have `style` attribute sticking. Till now, I have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".items ul li").each(function(){
    $(".items ul").width($(".items ul").width() + $(this).outerWidth());
    if ($(this).height() > $(".items").height())
      $(".items, .items ul").height($(this).outerHeight()+10);
  });
  $(".items ul").css("left", -$(".items ul li.current").prev().position().left);
  $(".items ul li:first").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("current"))
      return false;
    left = $(this).position().left-3-$(this).outerWidth();
    $(".items ul li").removeClass("current", 1200);
    $this = $(this);
    $(".items ul").animate({"left": -left+5}, 200, function() {
      $this.addClass("current", 1200);
    });
    return false;
  });
  $(".items ul li").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("current"))
      return false;
    left = $(this).prev().position().left+3;
    $(".items ul li").removeClass("current", 1200);
    $this = $(this);
    $(".items ul").animate({"left": -left+5}, 200, function() {
      $this.addClass("current", 1200);
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-size: 80%;}
.items {position: relative; width: 500px; overflow: hidden; margin: auto; padding: 15px;}
.items ul {position: absolute; top: 0;}
.items ul, .items ul li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; display: block; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 5px;}
.items ul li {display: block; width: 150px; text-align: center; float: left; margin: 0 5px; margin-top: 40px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;}
.items ul li a,
.items ul li a img,
.items ul li strong,
.items ul li span {display: block; margin: 5px 0;}
.items ul li a img {max-width: 100%;}
.items ul li.current {width: 200px; font-size: 1.2em; margin-top: 5px;}
.items ul li strong {font-size: 1.2em;}
.items ul li span {font-size: 1.1em;}
.items ul li a:first-child,
.items ul li a img {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x500" alt=""></a>
      <strong>Title 1</strong>
      <span>Subtitle 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x500" alt=""></a>
      <strong>Title 2</strong>
      <span>Subtitle 2</span>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x500" alt=""></a>
      <strong>Title 3</strong>
      <span>Subtitle 3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x500" alt=""></a>
      <strong>Title 4</strong>
      <span>Subtitle 4</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x500" alt=""></a>
      <strong>Title 5</strong>
      <span>Subtitle 5</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please press the <kbd>Run Snippet</kbd> twice. Seems like a loading issue bug.

I have the layout laid out like this:

[image: Layout]
[Full Size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KZVS.png) at Imgur.

Now when I try to use the below CSS:

```css
.items {width: 80%;}
.items ul li {width: 30%;}
.items ul li.current {width: 40%;}
```

The width of the parent (`<ul>`) is taken for the child slider elements, but it is the size of the whole contents of all the slides. I need the `<li>`s to take the relative `width` of its super-parent `.items`. Is this possible to achieve using pure CSS methods?

I know this can be done using jQuery, while every slide change or window's orientation change, but that adds a huge load of `style` attributes, which is not good in terms of performance. Any heads up on this? My final attempt will be making use of jQuery to add inline styles. I am looking for a pure CSS solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get some inspiration from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814838/make-div-100-of-grandparent-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.items` is always full-width, using vw (viewport width, as suggested by Clayton in the comments) will get a pure css solution, although you'll want to be careful with cross-browser testing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0n5nzo4/)

```
/* Responsiveness: */
.items {width: 80vw;}
.items ul li {width: 25vw;}
.items ul li.current {width: 30vw;}
.items li img {width:100%;}
```

If it just has to be relative to `.items`, I know of no pure css way to make a child a % width of it's parent's parent without absolute positioning (which would destroy your slider effect).