# Use % width on child element (but make percentage be based on previous/outer parent)

Tags: css, sass

I am making a responsive navigation and ran into a small issue, I am using SASS for the record....

Anyone know of a way I can make a child element a percentage width based on either the width of the users viewport at the time or on the outer outer parent...see below...

```
<div class="outer-parent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
```

As I said it can either be a percentage width based on the viewport or on one of the further outer parents.

Screenshot of HTML layout:
[image]

Thanks Guys,
Kieran

Comment: If you have parent element set to 30% width, child element set to 50% will be half of the parent 30%.

Comment: @ValentinoKožinec Yep but I want the functionality to be.... outer parent 100% of the entire viewport (so in my case the navigation container)... parent to be the navigation items (so there would be multiple of these with a width of auto (meaning there contents will decide the width).... then the child (being the dropdown menu) should be a percentage width of the entire page or the outer parent.

Comment: Please refer to this question [Make Div 100% of grandparent container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814838/make-div-100-of-grandparent-container)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
.parent{
  width = 90vw;

  .child {
    width = 50%; //50 % of 90vw.
  }
}
```

Look an example without setting a value to the parent width

```css
.oldParent {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 50%; #this will be 50% of the parent width, no matter what width the parrent has"
 }
```

```html
<div class="oldParent">
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     Child 1
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     Child2
   </div>
   <div class="child">
    Child 3
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using setting a width on the parent as I am currently using flex so my width is set to auto, this is because the parent in this example is the navigation item. Then the child is the dropdown menu which I want to be a percentage width of the entire page, or the entire navigation container. (Also sorry about no code examples just the code is long and complex it would probably make the question less clear)

Comment: but that will work, for example if you have the parent lets say to an auto width, then by setting the width of the child it will take in relation to the parent.

Comment: No because if I set the parent to width=auto and lets say the text within parent is "Home", this would make the size about 20px wide lets say, automatically. Then it would mean if I set the child width to 50% it will inherit this width of 20px get 50% which is 10px wide. Whereas I want the width of outer-parent which lets say is 500px wide to be the one it inherits from. Get what I mean?

Comment: That is confusing for me, could you provide us with the HTML and maybe a sketch of what you want?

Comment: Im am not sure if you can set the width of the `outerParent` to the `child`, cuz it's first parent is `parent` and it will inherit his width. Unless you use `vw` or `javascript` or make it absolute. But why dont you make the `child` div a `child` of `outerparent`?

Comment: I will attach a screenshot of my html layout to the ticket so you can see what I mean pal.

Comment: I got it now, please check my comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much space `.parent` uses of `.outer-parent`, you could do something like this.

```
.parent {
    width: 50%;

    .child {
        width: percentage(30 / 50);
        /* 30% of .outer-parent == 60% of .parent */
    }
}
```